# Redirect product url with category path

Tags: product, category, url-rewrite, base-url, category-products

I had a store with category path turned on for product urls. After realising that, it creates duplicate content issues in SEO, I turned it off.
Since product urls (with category path) are already linked in Social Media and Email Campaigns, Google Analytics tracking is showing lots of such visited urls.

Now I am trying to redirect the product with category path to the one having product url key only.
For example:
http://mystore.com/category/sub-category/product.html --> http://mystore.com/product.html
http://mystore.com/category/product.html --> http://mystore.com/product.html

I tried to use the following script which implements the event `controller_action_predispatch` but it's not working as expected:

```
public function controllerActionPredispatch(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $action         = $observer->getControllerAction();
    $request        = $action->getRequest();
    $requestUrl     = isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ? $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : $request->getRequestUri();
    $fullActionName = $action->getFullActionName();
    $storeId        = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();

    if (in_array($fullActionName, array('catalog_product_view'))) {
        $product  = Mage::registry('current_product');
        $category = Mage::registry('current_category');
        if ($product && $product->getId() && $category && $category->getId()) {
            $categoryUrlKey = $this->getCategoryUrlKey($category->getId(), $storeId);
            if (empty($categoryUrlKey)) {
                $categoryUrlKey = $category->getUrlKey();
            }

            if (stripos($requestUrl, '/' . $categoryUrlKey . '/') !== false) {
                $urlKey = $this->getProductUrlKey($product->getId(), $storeId);
                if (empty($urlKey)) {
                    $urlKey = $product->getUrlKey();
                }
                $redirectUrl = Mage::getUrl() . trim($urlKey, '/') . '.html';
                $action->getResponse()->setRedirect($redirectUrl, 301);
                $action->getRequest()->setDispatched(true);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

public function getCategoryUrlKey($categoryId, $storeId = 0)
{
    $resource   = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $connection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
    $sql        = "select value from catalog_category_entity_url_key where entity_id = ? and store_id = ? limit 1";
    $urlKey     = $connection->fetchOne($sql, array($categoryId, $storeId));
    return $urlKey;
}

public function getProductUrlKey($productId, $storeId = 0)
{
    $resource   = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $connection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
    $sql        = "select value from catalog_product_entity_url_key where entity_id = ? and store_id = ? limit 1";
    $urlKey     = $connection->fetchOne($sql, array($productId, $storeId));
    return $urlKey;
}
```

Any idea for the perfect solution?
I am using #Magento #EE version 1.13.

[Edit]
One strange thing is

```
$action->getResponse()->setRedirect($redirectUrl, 301);
$action->getRequest()->setDispatched(true);
```

redirection doesn't work in live server but works in localhost.

Answer (score 1):

If you want exclude category url from product  url for new  product you need enable setting from `admin>system>catalog>Catalog>Search` engine Optimization> Use Categories Path for Product URLs`make it`no`also`Create Permanent Redirect for URLs if URL Key Changed`it`yes`

Here some other trick

```
http://www.doingthing.com/blog/item/1164
http://www.mikesmullin.com/development/use-categories-product-urls-magento-seo-without-duplicate-content/
```

Here the another process of This task...

**Step1:** create `a backup core_url_rewrite` table with table `data and it structure`.

**Step2:** create another `duplicate table  of core_url_rewrite`  using my query
below:

```
CREATE  TABLE  `core_url_rewrite_dump` (  `url_rewrite_id` int( 10  )  unsigned NOT  NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT  COMMENT  'Rewrite Id',
 `store_id` smallint( 5  )  unsigned NOT  NULL DEFAULT  '0' COMMENT  'Store Id',
 `id_path` varchar( 255  )  DEFAULT NULL  COMMENT  'Id Path',
 `request_path` varchar( 255  )  DEFAULT NULL  COMMENT  'Request Path',
 `target_path` varchar( 255  )  DEFAULT NULL  COMMENT  'Target Path',
 `is_system` smallint( 5  ) unsigned DEFAULT  '1' COMMENT  'Defines is Rewrite System',
 `options` varchar( 255  )  DEFAULT NULL  COMMENT  'Options',
 `description` varchar( 255  )  DEFAULT NULL  COMMENT  'Deascription',
 `category_id` int( 10  ) unsigned  DEFAULT NULL  COMMENT  'Category Id',
 `product_id` int( 10  ) unsigned  DEFAULT NULL  COMMENT  'Product Id',
 PRIMARY  KEY (  `url_rewrite_id`  ) ,
 UNIQUE  KEY  `UNQ_CORE_URL_REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_STORE_ID` (  `request_path` ,  `store_id`  ) ,
 UNIQUE  KEY  `UNQ_CORE_URL_REWRITE_ID_PATH_IS_SYSTEM_STORE_ID` (  `id_path` ,  `is_system` ,  `store_id`  ) ,
 KEY  `IDX_CORE_URL_REWRITE_TARGET_PATH_STORE_ID` (  `target_path` ,  `store_id`  ) ,
 KEY  `IDX_CORE_URL_REWRITE_ID_PATH` (  `id_path`  ) ,
 KEY  `IDX_CORE_URL_REWRITE_STORE_ID` (  `store_id`  ) ,
 KEY  `FK_CORE_URL_REWRITE_CTGR_ID_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_ENTT_ID` (  `category_id`  ) ,
 KEY  `FK_CORE_URL_REWRITE_PRODUCT_ID_CATALOG_CATEGORY_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID` (  `product_id`  )  ) ENGINE  = InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET  = utf8 COMMENT  =  'Url Rewrites';

SET SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO';

INSERT INTO `core_url_rewrite_dump` SELECT * FROM `magento1702v1`.`core_url_rewrite
```

**Step4:**

final run the below code

```
UPDATE `magento1702v1`.`core_url_rewrite` as p  SET `target_path`=(SELECT rurl.request_path
FROM `core_url_rewrite_dump` as rurl
WHERE rurl.product_id IS NOT NULL
AND rurl.category_id IS NULL 
AND rurl.product_id=p.product_id
LIMIT 0 , 1)  
,`options` = 'RP' 
WHERE p. product_id IS NOT NULL
AND p.category_id  IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: You can still open product with category path even it's set to NO.

Comment: try my another processs

Comment: I forgot to mention that this is for Magento EE.

Comment: had you tried my solution???

Comment: The reason I am mentioning that I am using Magento EE is, it doesn't use core_url_rewrite (which is blank in my case) but used enterprise_url_rewrite* tables.

Comment: then just use  enterprise_url_rewrite instead   ofcore_url_rewrite  in all place

Comment: Nope you can't as it has different fields and product_id, category_id, options etc. fields are not there.

Comment: This get's broken when you reindex

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend the following module (https://www.scommerce-mage.co.uk/magento-seo-catalog-urls.html) which allows you to have unique product URL for your website with or without category path. Choosing or defining the product URL is quite flexible. You can choose either of the following URL and all the URLs will be redirecting to the URL of your choice -:

> http://mystore.com/product.html

or

> http://mystore.com/category/product.html

or

> http://mystore.com/category/subcategory/product.html

This has reduced duplicate content issue on our website so hope to help others in the community. Hope it helps. Thanks